# How to obtain Comparison type of priority_queue?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, priority-queue, std

Most similar containers have member types like `key_compare` or `value_compare` but there [none](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue#Member_types) for `priority_queue`.

Is that because `priority_queue` is an adaptor? Or is this in the standard by mistake?

Comment: I submitted an LWG issue.

Comment: Where to track the issue status?

Comment: https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2684

Comment: This is now a C++17 feature!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is weird indeed and seems to be an oversight in the C++ standard. The standard declares `priority_queue` as:

```
template <class T,
          class Container = vector<T>,
          class Compare = less<typename Container::value_type> >
class priority_queue;
```

And while it specifies the following public members:

```
typedef typename Container::value_type value_type;
typedef typename Container::reference reference;
typedef typename Container::const_reference const_reference;
typedef typename Container::size_type size_type;
typedef Container container_type;
```

it for some reason omits a `typedef Compare value_compare;` declaration. A C++ Standard Library [issue for this](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2684) has been submitted to the Library Working Group (LWG) by SO user Columbo.

### Workarounds

However, you can use the following to work around the issue.

#### In C++11 and later

```
#include <queue>

template <typename> struct GetCompare;

template <typename T, typename Container, typename Compare>
struct GetCompare<std::priority_queue<T, Container, Compare> >
{ using type = Compare; };

template <typename T>
using GetCompare_t = typename GetCompare<T>::type;
```

For example:

```
#include <type_traits>

static_assert(
    std::is_same<
        GetCompare_t<std::priority_queue<int> >,
        std::less<int>
    >::value, "");
```

#### In C++03 and earlier

```
#include <queue>

template <typename> struct GetCompare;

template <typename T, typename Container, typename Compare>
struct GetCompare<std::priority_queue<T, Container, Compare> >
{ typedef Compare type; };
```

For example:

```
int main() {
    return typename GetCompare<std::priority_queue<int> >::type()(42, 0);
}
```